# Crazy Auction custom sell price

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

In CA you can only write a price in command `/ca sell %price%`.
For my server, I tried to make it easier with NPC you clicking on, and enter your price, but it doesn't work at all. Not even messages in the log.

In general, I tried to create this:

if executed /youridea

- send message "enter price"
- get player's message
- execute "/ca sell" + player's message

main class:

```
package me.deginech.uridea;

import me.deginech.uridea.sender.youridea;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerRespawnEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class URIDEA extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("You pick ou the wrong door.");
        getCommand("youridea").setExecutor(new youridea());
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        System.out.println("My battery is low, and it's getting dark");
    }
}
```

Another one:

```
package me.deginech.uridea.sender;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

public class youridea implements CommandExecutor, Listener {


    @EventHandler
    public boolean onCommand(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event, CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args){
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            player.sendMessage("§6Enter your price.");
            String msg = event.getMessage();
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.performCommand("ca sell" + msg);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender commandSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Core - Paper-spigot 1.16.1

Please, tell me: What did I do wrong?

Comment: Might want to try over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com if it doesn't get enough attention here.

Comment: I doubt it will get any attention on gamedev either.  This question is really best on a spigot forum, as the question is about the API, not the programming.

Comment: Also, when/if you do move it to a spigot forum, I highly recommend trying to narrow down the question first.  What I see here is a bunch of code and a "why doesn't it work".  What doesn't work?  What is each method supposed to do?  Is your plugin running at all?  Some basic debugging information would help.